# Regex: Match an Alphanumeric string that could contain the characther '-'

Tags: regex

Eg: "_V9DXkFMCEeGrv54B-L8--A"

`\w+` alone will not work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
[\w-]+
```

Answer (score 2):

use this pattern: `[-\w]+` \w is an alpanumeric character. Actually pattern depends from your language. For example in java you have to write `[-\\w]+` and there also can be languages where `-` is a special character and you should escape it too. So please edit your question and add the language you use.